# Reading KeyValueConfigurationElement

Tags: c#

I try to load the app settings of my self-defined setting tag but I got the following error:

> Error 62  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement[]'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Do you have any idea how to solve this? The code I have is as follows:

```
KeyValueConfigurationElement[] test = (from KeyValueConfigurationElement e in ((AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("mySection")).Settings
                                                                       where e.Value == "1"
                                                                       select e);
```

It highlighted the error at "where" in the code. I think this is quite simple but I can't solve it, tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `.ToArray()` to the end of your expression:

```
KeyValueConfigurationElement[] test = (from KeyValueConfigurationElement e in ((AppSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("mySection")).Settings
        where e.Value == "1"
        select e).ToArray();
```